# Vuetify v-flex width specifications

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I can't find any proper references for the `xs`, `sm`, `md`, `lg` and `xl` directives of `v-flex` in Vuetify. If I want two columns in extra small layouts, three in small layouts, four in medium layouts, six in large layouts, and 12 in extra-large layouts, then is this the correct HTML?

```
<v-flex xs2 sm3 md4 lg6 xl12>
    Mostly harmless.
</v-flex>
```

Comment: It's vice-versa. See docs https://vuetifyjs.com/en/layout/grid#usage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The numeric portion of the attribute refers to the number of columns the `v-flex` will span in a 12 column layout. So, `xs1` will be 1 of 12 columns whereas xs12 will be 12 of 12 columns.

Here's a visual demo.

```js
new Vue({
  data() {
    return {
      cols: 12
    }
  },
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    color() {
      return this.hexToRgb(Math.random().toString(16).substr(2, 6))
    },
    hexToRgb(hex) {
      var bigint = parseInt(hex, 16);
      var r = (bigint >> 16) & 255;
      var g = (bigint >> 8) & 255;
      var b = bigint & 255;

      return r + "," + g + "," + b;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-content>
      <v-container fluid grid-list-md>
        <v-layout row wrap>
          <template v-for="c in cols">
            <v-flex v-for="i in Math.floor(cols/c)" :key="`${c}-${i}`" :class="`xs${c} text-xs-center`" :style="{ backgroundColor: `rgba(${color()},.4)` }">
              <b>xs{{ c }}</b>
            </v-flex>
          </template>
        </v-layout>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>
```